# How to wrap an instance using Guice

Tags: guice, cglib

I am using Guice. I want to enhance a instance using CGLIB. Basically I want Guice to provide the instance but I want to wrap that instance with Enhancer before returning it.
I thought of using Provider, however I want Guice to resolve the dependencies and give me the instance so I can wrap it and return the Enhanced version.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Provider should do the trick, can you supply your code ? Specialy the class you want to inject, and how you wrap it.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple options, depending on how much injection flexibility you need.

One way is to create your instance yourself, enhance it as you see fit, and then [inject the fields and methods using an injected `MembersInjector`](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/MembersInjector.html) as needed. This precludes you from using constructor injection, or at least requires you to fulfill constructor injection yourself, but does the trick cleanly:

```
public class YourModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override public void configure() { }

  @Provides YourClass provideEnhancedYourClass(
      MembersInjector<YourClass> yourClassInjector,
      YourDependency dependency) {
    YourClass yourClass = YourClassEnhancer.enhance(new YourClass(dependency));
    yourClassInjector.injectMembers(yourClass);
    return yourClass;
  }
}
```

Another way is a little more complicated, because Guice needs to be able to provide the instance by some key and also inject it by some key. You do get to use constructor injection, but you also have to use [binding annotations](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations) so you don't recursively depend on an enhanced YourClass to create an enhanced YourClass:

```
@BindingAnnotation @Target({ FIELD, PARAMETER, METHOD }) @Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Enhanced {}

public class YourModule extends AbstractModule {

  @Provides @Enhanced
  YourClass provideEnhancedYourClass(YourClass yourClass) {
    return YourClassEnhancer.enhance(yourClass);
  }
}
```

The trick is, to keep them separate, you need to ask for an injection of `@Enhanced YourClass` rather than just `YourClass`. You might be able to figure out a way to return the class without needing that annotation, especially if you extract an interface and phrase it like `@Provides YourInterface providesEnhancedYourClass(YourClass class)`, but either way it has to be a little more complicated to let Guice provide an unenhanced class for you to enhance.